# Angular 2 "Cannot match any routes" on named outlet

Tags: angular

In the follwing plunkr, if you remove the outlet name attribute in `app/app.ts` and the outlet param in the route of `app/desk.module` it will all work fine and load into the standard outlet.

https://plnkr.co/edit/SYAyiZUvJjDx1ydZqsrE

I would expect the same in a named outlet. But obviously that doesn't work. The error that comes up is "Cannot match any routes".

Is this a bug in angular? Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `redirecTo` for named outlet :

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'board'},
{ path: 'board', component: BoardComponent, outlet: 'board'}
```

Here the first route definition will redirect to `board` **on the main outlet** and there is no route defined to match that.

Comment: That sounds reasonable but when I change it, it has exactly the same error.

Comment: when you change what ?

Comment: remove the redirect path